# Модель JTable и массив объектов

Tags: jtable, java, swing

Я только начинаю изучать Java, поэтому вопрос может показаться абсолютно глупым, но вот не въеду никак.

Суть такова. Имеем табличку `JTable` и огромное количество файлов. Из файлов вытаскивается определенная информация (грубо говоря, теги, объекты `String`), и для каждого такого файла создается экземпляр класса(назовём его `FileTags`), который хранит имя файла, абсолютный путь к нему и эти самые теги.

Отображается это все через таблицу `JTable`. Правильно ли я понял, что надо унаследовать модель от `AbstractTableModel`, передать ей в качестве данных массив объектов `FileTags`, а затем в конструкторе модели вытащить нужные поля из объектов `FileTags` и отобразить их в таблицу? Или тут как-то иначе всё работает?
Заранее спасибо за помощь.